# Amplify init not running

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, aws-amplify

When I try to initialize Amplify through amplify init in my project route,I get an error message. The error is :

*cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170*.

I've tried to run amplify init on the CLI(not inside vsc) and it has worked. I was able to succesfully create a backend with amplify. The error only occurs when I try to initialize amplify inside my project CLI

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this and that is to run powershell as admin and add this line into it:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

This should allow amplify init to run in the root of your project